# ractive.observe('*') is causing a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ractivejs

Basically I have a "parent-ractive-view" that takes in a decorator, That decorator would then create another ractive-view, and observe all of it's viewModelData, if I use `view.observe('*')` (with some special template syntax) then I get an error.

I really don't know how to explain this without an example

(Tested in Mac OS 10.10 Chrome 38.0.2125.111)

- Open this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYwLOp
- Open your developer tools console
- Click on "John Smith"
- See a  `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in the console

## If you saw the example, keep reading

### Ways to avoid seeing the error

(also mentioned in the example's source as comments)

#### If you do not use `view.observe('*', callback)`

at all or even use a space-separated name the properties to observe, instead of using the global wildcard, `*`, i.e. `view.observe('prop1.* prop2 prop3.*')`, the error does not occur.

#### if you modify this line this line, the error does not occur, what is wrong with this line O.o

(only look at that first parenthese)

FROM

```
    <div class="{{#if (karma * age) >= 1}}transparent-90{{else}}transparent 25{{/if}}">karma: {{karma}}, age: {{age}} </div>
```

TO

```
    <div class="{{#if (karma + 1) >= 1}}transparent-90{{else}}transparent 25{{/if}}">karma: {{karma}}, age: {{age}} </div>
```

OR-TO (weird)

```
    <div class="{{#if (5 * age) >= 1}}transparent-90{{else}}transparent 25{{/if}}">karma: {{karma}}, age: {{age}} </div>
```

### What I initially thought, and turned out to be wrong

(something is not breaking the `PatternObserver.update` recursive call)

- There are some circular references from the decorator's scope to `Ractive.defaults.data`, so I removed all default properties.
- Collision of namespace between parent-view and decorator-view, nope, I changed property names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially a ractivejs bug, Meanwhile, don't use `(a * b)` for multiplication, use `( a / (1/b) )`

follow this thread, https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1472